# Formatting/Organizing Data In Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a scraper, scraping yellowpages.  It is outputting all of my data correctly.  What I am trying to figure out is how to more or less format the out put to line up next to each other.  SO instead of output looking like

> Dataset1
>
> Dataset2
>
> Dataset3

I would want to format it looking like

> Dataset1 Dataset2 Dataset3

So now the data lines up to each other in columns, instead of one long row.

I will post my code.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.yellowpages.com/austin-tx/screen-printing?g=Austin%2C+TX&q=screen+printing"))

business_name = page.css("div.srp-business-name")
#links = page.css("a.track-visit-website")
phone_number = page.css("span.business-phone")


companies = page.css('#results div.result')
companies.each do |company|
    website_link = company.at_css("a.track-visit-website")
    if website_link
        puts website_link['href']
    else
        puts 'no website'
    end
end

puts phone_number.text
puts business_name.text
```

Comment: Did you try to strip the string of newlines? And what about using double quotes instead of single quotes in the `puts` line?

Comment: ya it doesnt quite do what im wanting.  I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question well, it is not really related to Nokogiri. You might want to use `print` instead of `puts`, which prints a string without adding a new line at the end.

Or yet,

```
companies = page.css('#results div.result')
website_links = []
companies.each do |company|
    website_link = company.at_css("a.track-visit-website")
    website_links << website_link || 'no website'
end

puts "#{website_links.join(' ')}, #{phone_number.text}, #{business_name.text}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how familiar you are with Ruby, but what I do in such situations is to use `irb` (look it up if unfamiliar). I enter the code line by line. I then inspect the variables, see what's happening and then try out some solutions.

In your case, the `phone_number.text` you get back is in the following form:

```
"\nDataset1\n\nDataset2\n\nDataset3\n\nDataset4\n"
```

This explains your result. If you strip this, it will only remove the newlines at the beginning and end of the string.

What you need to do is use something like `gsub` to substitute all the newlines with space (or whatever you want). I'm choosing to use space as an example.

```
puts phone_number.text.strip.gsub("\n", " ")
```

will print out:

```
"Dataset1  Dataset2  Dataset3  Dataset4"
```

Answer (score -1):

I havent figured it out just yet, but in the mean time was able to format it in a much more readable version, so I am going to call it quits for now.  I can work that functionality in later.  Here is the script if you would like to play with it.

```
companies = doc.css('#results div.result')

companies.each do | info|
   business_name = info.at_css('div.srp-business-name')
   phone_number = info.at_css("span.business-phone")
   website_link = info.at_css("a.track-visit-website")

   if business_name
      puts business_name.text
      puts phone_number.text
      if website_link
         puts website_link['href']
         puts "----------------------------"
      else
         puts "no website"
         puts "----------------------------"
      end
   end
end
```